# Magento Multi-tenant compliation

Tags: setup-di-compile

What exactly is a multi-tenant compiler in Magento as referred in this link: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html?

Answer (score 0):

It was a previous way to do code compilation but was removed entirely in 2016: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/6bb447cbcacb9974a072aebdf31fd1e9ed7dc7c6

That notice was just outdated. I just pushed a PR to remove.